# mnemosyne crashes in debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

I have desktop and a laptop with debian running on them both. in the Desktop mnemosyne crashes just from opening or maximixing the window. The laptop is perfect. they are both lenovo.

hugo@debian:~$ running mnemosyne from command line

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29.png
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29.png
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29_1_.png
Segmentation fault

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29.png
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29.png
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29_1_.png
Segmentation fault
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29.png
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29.png
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
QIODevice::write (QProcess): device not open
Missing path home/hugo/.local/share/mnemosyne/default.db_media/Screenshot from 2018-11-24 09-54-29_1_.png
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Then fill a [bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=mnemosyne;dist=stable).

Answer (score 0):

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=883333. I had the same issue, but manually installing some additional packages solved it for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the specific packages and steps you had to take to answer this question?